# Parsing weather data and sort it in collection

Tags: java, android, sorting, weather

Got stuck at the following: I'm parsing xml weather data containing info about 3 different

```
weather stations:

<station>
<station_id>TAPA</station_id>
<latitude>17.117</latitude>
<longitude>-61.783</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TAPA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_id>TKPN</station_id>
<latitude>17.2</latitude>
<longitude>-62.583</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TKPN.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_name>Blackburne/Plymouth</station_name>
<latitude>16.75</latitude>
<longitude>-62.167</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TRPM.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

Next, i'm getting their distances to my device and getting the following data set:

```
Distance(Double):        Corresponding XML(String)

3495.3          http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TAPA.xml
1234.4          http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TKPN.xml
5678.7          http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TRPM.xml
```

What's the best way to put them in some kind of a sorted collection in ascending order and get the lowest distance to obtain corresponding xml file? I mean, the Distance would be Key and Corresponding XML would be its value. After sorting I would get the lowest distance(which is the first Key) and access my url to perform some other work on it. The distances may change because there may be other stations nearby so somehow I need to access the very first Key-Value pair. Could you please give me a hint on that.

Comment: Make the object representing the data Implement `Comparable`, then override the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is how it works:

To be able to `sort` objects by a `property` in java, you have to implement the `Comparable` interface. Then, you need to override the method called `compareTo()` which uses the current instance (`this`) and an additional one to sort them in the proper order. So, to be able to sort by the distance between the stations, you need to do something like this:

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data>{
    String url;
    double distance;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data other){
        // compareTo should return < 0 if this is supposed to be
        // less than other, > 0 if this is supposed to be greater than 
        // other and 0 if they are supposed to be equal
        int result = this.distance <= other.distance ? -1 : 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

After doing this, you are going to be able to call:

```
Collections.sort(dataList);
```

And, you'll have your objects sorted by the distance property.

Answer (score 1):

well I would like to add few things as @Luis Lavierim has covered necessary things.

given xml needs root element as it is invalid now because of multiple root elements

I have written a test code assuming a root element `<root></root>`

you may use [simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library to parse the data which is quite easy.

```
            Serializer serializer_Read = new Persister();
            File source = new File(path);
            Response response = serializer_Read.read(Response.class, source);

            Collections.sort(response.getStations());
            System.out.println("" + response.getStations().size());
            for (Station station : response.getStations()) {
                System.out.println("" + station.getStation_id());
            }
```

well you will require some type to do the sort against it, you check this model class for the response. the code is also available on [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/tree/master/SimpleXMLFrameworkSample/src/stack/overflow/one) and it's been tested

```
@Root(name = "root", strict = false)
class Response {

    @ElementList(name = "station", inline = true)
    List<Station> stations;


    public List<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }
}

@Root(name = "station", strict = false)
class Station implements Comparable<Station> {

    @Element(name = "station_id", required = false)
    private String station_id;

    @Element(name = "latitude", required = false)
    private String latitude;

    @Element(name = "longitude", required = false)
    private String longitude;

    @Element(name = "xml_url", required = false)
    private String xml_url;

    @Element(name = "distance", required = true)
    private int distance;

    public Station() {
    }

    public Station(String station_id, String latitude, String longitude, String xml_url) {
        this.station_id = station_id;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.xml_url = xml_url;
    }

    public String getStation_id() {
        return station_id;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getXml_url() {
        return xml_url;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Station o) {
        Station station = (Station) o;
        return this.distance - station.getDistance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its a bit complicated for my level of knowledge, but I will definitely study it.

Comment: @androider, it's ok, use the library documentation, it's really easy, i have written some example regarding library is you would like to check https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/tree/master/SimpleXMLFrameworkSample/src/example/simple/xml/framework